# Buttons in a report are not working in oracle application apex

Tags: oracle

I tried to create a form with report page in an application from apex, but the buttons create, save and delete does not appear to work whenever I click on them.

The edit option is enabled so I do not know what the problem might be.
[image]

There are the buttons:
[image]
This is what appears at delete:
[image]

I would like to know if you can help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you posted, it looks as if it is an **interactive grid** (IG) (not any kind of "report"). In that case, the only button you need is located in IGs toolbar, and its default label is **Save**.

Therefore, you can

- use the "Add row" button to insert new rows
- update existing values
- delete rows using the *hamburger* icon in each row (or for the whole grid)

and then press the "Save" button to save changes you've made.

---

Separate buttons you mention are related to a form. If you do have it, then buttons themselves aren't enough. Apex creates the *automatic row processing* process by default, but - if you created everything on your own, you'll also have to create that process because it just won't work without it.

Comment: I forgot to mention it is an interactive report.